# How to change the path of the file to be created in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm using CMake to build the code. It creates a subdirectory `src/a.out` and stores the output file. Until now I'm defining the path manually if I want to store the created file some place else e.g., like this

```cpp
std::ofstream ofile;
ofile.open("/home/results/foo.txt");
```

I'd like to know is there a way I can define the path in CMake rather than in code?

Comment: One options is to pass the path in as a preprocessor definition from CMake. Probably not the best way though.

Comment: `configure_file` could be used to generate a header file containing the file path as a constant, but not sure, if this is actually the best option here. Passing the path as command line argument to the program may be a better option depending on what you're going for. For the visual studio debugger it's possible to specify the settings via `VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS`, but for other generators you may need to create a custom target to be able to run the program from command line by building a certain cmake target...

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to pass the path through compiler arguments.

```
project( test )
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0 )
add_executable( testparm testparm.cpp )
target_compile_options( testparm PUBLIC -DMYPATH=/tmp/file.txt )
```

In testparm.cpp

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
int main() {
        const char* path = TOSTRING(MYPATH);
        std::ofstream file( path );
        file << "Hello World\n";
        return 0;
}
```

Running:

```sh
$ strace ./testparm
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/file.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
write(3, "Hello World\n", 12)           = 12
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)
```